# Ember-cli-compass-compiler: how to override the default options?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using [ember-cli-compass-compiler](https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-compass-compiler) right now, it works well if only compass used, but I also want to use some plugins, such as Susy. I don't know how to require plugins with compass.

I've try to read the source code, founded it has a option object and includes `require: sass-CSS-importer` by default, but how to override/extend this option? What code should I put in Broccoli.js file?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure this out by myself, in case of someone needs help, I put my solution at here:

Open `Brocfile.js` and find this line:

```js
var app = new EmberApp();
```

then, change it to:

```js
var app = new EmberApp({
  compassOptions: {
    require: ['sass-css-importer', 'susy']
  }
});
```

this assumes you want to use Susy as well as me, and of course you can override other options like above.

BTW, if you use sass syntax checker, e.g. syntastic in vim, `@import "susy";` will rise an error about *load path* problem. Before using Ember-CLI, I use a `config.rb` as compass's configurations, so sass knows about `require "susy"` is a dependency should be concerned about. But now we no longer have `config.rb` file anymore, fortunately you can let sass knows required gem(s) by passing `-r GEM_NAME` to passing the syntax checker. For case of syntastic, you can simply put this line in your `.vimrc` file:

```sh
let g:syntastic_scss_sass_args = "-r sass-css-importer -r susy"
```